# Can a DLL project of VS use/return CLR types?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll

I am trying to code up a DLL that does a bunch of things, including file I/O, string split, processing, output a lot of information. I am using VS2008, .net 3.5, C++

I followed this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

First I build a caller(tester) project in the solution and try to call a test function in the dll, and that works. So I proceed to turn on CLR compile flag in the DLL, so that I can do string processing easier. But that gives me a link error. I tried turning on the CLR compile flag in the caller project and suddenly i have two link error.

What do i have to do to be able to use CLR inside DLL and be able to return the result as an object back to the caller?

Comment: Is the caller of your DLL also managed?

Comment: @Martyn Lovell yes it it. Right now the caller is also Visual C++. It is in the same solution as the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass CLR types through flat APIs at the DLL boundary. But only other C++-based /clr code would be able to consume them. And because there is just one IAT for a process, this won't always work right if you have multiple appdomains.

The recommended way to pass managed types would be through direct managed references.

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

Put your functions inside a

```
public ref struct
```

and then using managed types for parameters and return values becomes very straightforward.

If you want to call the functions without creating an object first, make them static.